# The module is not displayed in DisplayLeftColumn

Tags: module, prestashop

I have a problem with Prestashop 1.7.x.
I create a basic module and I registered for the first time to DisplayLeftColumn then to displayHome and then back to DisplayLeftColumn.
I can install the module with no errors, and the position it's set ok in the backoffice, but not show anything.

Thanks in advance!

```
    if(!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
        exit;

    class homephoto extends Module{
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->name = 'homephoto';
            $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
            $this->version = '1.0';
            $this->author = 'PlusPlusDesign';
            $this->ps_version_compilancy = array('min'=>'1.5', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
            $this->need_instance = 0;
            $this->bootstrap = true;
            $this->displayName = $this->l('home photo');
            $this->description = $this->l('This is for the mainpage');
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function install(){
            if(!parent::install() or !$this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn'))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public function displayLeftColumn($params){
            return 'Hello World';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cache is disabled!

Answer (score 0):

Change your hook function:

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of available hooks, with information to know where he is called, and what he does : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

Then in the module add "hook" in front to be able to call it as a function and so it can be called.

Ex : In your code : "displayLeftColumn" and in your module  function : hookDisplayLeftColumn

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `hook` to your function to be called. See the example below :

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
```